# How to import settings of opera from windows 7 to 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, opera

I want to import all the settings including bookmarks,speed dial, etc from opera in windows to Ubuntu 11.10.
Tell me how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera has a sync functionality, called [Opera Link](http://www.opera.com/link/). It will synchronize your Bookmarks, Passwords and Speed Dial online via an Opera Account. You can use this to safely upload your settings in Windows and then download by signing in to the same Opera Account in Ubuntu.

In addition to your Bookmarks, Passwords, and Speed Dial, it will also synchronize you Notes, Typed browser history, Search engines, and Content blocker rules. You can individually disable synchronization of any of these individually during the setup process.

[Learn How To Use Opera Link](http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/link/)